Заполнение формы загрузки файла FLASK
В ORM-модели имею следующее поле для файла миниатюры:
  thumbnail_file = FileField('Файл аннотации')

Имею подобную форму с добавлением файла миниатюры:
@app.route("/add-job", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def add_job():
    ...
    filename = secure_filename(form.thumbnail_file.data.filename)
    if filename:
        form.thumbnail_file.data.save(f'static/img/cases/{filename.replace(' ', '-')}')
        logging.info(f"Изображение сохранено в static/img/{filename}")
        job = Jobs(
            job=form.job.data,
            team_leader=form.team_leader.data.split(".")[0],
            collaborators=",".join(collaborator.split(".")[0] for collaborator in form.collaborators.data),
            work_size=form.work_size.data,
            category=form.category.data,
            is_finished=form.is_finished.data,
            thumbnail_file=filename
        )
    ...

При изменении формы подгружаю в неё все поля, включая поле загрузки файла
@app.route("/edit-job/<int:job_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_job(job_id):
    db_sess = db_session.create_session()
    user_full_names_and_ids = {user.id: f"{user.name} {user.surname}" for user in db_sess.query(User).all()}
    category_ids = tuple(category_id[0] for category_id in db_sess.query(Category.id).all())
    form = AddJobForm(tuple(f"{user_id}. {user_full_name}" for user_id, user_full_name
                            in user_full_names_and_ids.items()), category_ids)
    if request.method == "GET":
        jobs = db_sess.query(Jobs).filter(Jobs.id == job_id,
                                          (Jobs.team_leader == current_user.id) | (
                                                  current_user.id == 1)).first()
        if jobs:
            form.job.data = jobs.job
            form.team_leader.data = f"{jobs.team_leader}. {user_full_names_and_ids[jobs.team_leader]}"
            form.collaborators.data = tuple(f"{int(collaborator_id)}. {user_full_names_and_ids[int(collaborator_id)]}"
                                            for collaborator_id in jobs.collaborators.split(","))
            form.work_size.data = jobs.work_size
            form.category.data = jobs.category
            form.is_finished.data = jobs.is_finished
            if jobs.thumbnail_file:
                with open(f'static/img/cases/{jobs.thumbnail_file}', 'rb') as file:
                    form.thumbnail_file.data = FileStorage(stream=file, filename=file.name, content_type='image/png')
        else:
            abort(404)
            ...

Но, к сожалению, при моём решении ничего не подгружается. Пожалуйста, помогите(
